# Magento 1 SQL Queries

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql

I am in the process of setting up some reporting functionality for my company, Im gathering data from the likes of Google, Moz and our Courier. As part of the reporting I also want to get data from Magento. As this will be hosted in a very secure folder on our server. What I would like to know is what is the safest way for me to run queries on the Magento Data?

I could run

- Direct SQL queries outside of Magento
- SQL queries inside Magento but then would have issues getting them out of Magento automatically
- Magento API

Which am I best doing from a safety and performance point of view for my website?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes you can run direct sql queries within Magento, the best way to do this is to use the read write resource. You can insatiate it with:

```
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

    $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
```

To run a select you can do something like this:

```
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('catalog/product');

    $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

    /* get the results */
    var_dump($results);
```

To write something to the database use:

```
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

    $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

    $table = $resource->getTableName('catalog/product');

    $query = "UPDATE {$table} SET {item} = '{value}' WHERE entity_id = 'value'";

    $writeConnection->query($query);
```

Hope this helps out for you.

Comment: Thanks @Kay do you know what the consequences would be of me querying the db outside of Magento?

Comment: Not that much, its just not best practice. and you can risk inconsistencies but normally no problem. but now you keep it all tight in one workflow

Comment: Where to find all of these queries ?

Comment: Please keep in mind that writing to the database in this way introduces a **SQL injection vulnerability**. Only do this if you are _sure_ that your values are safe.

Answer (score 28):

There is a more proper way to do this to avoid SQL Injections.

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$write = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$table = $resource->getTableName('your/model');
```

You can Create:

```
$write->insert(
    $table, 
    ['column_1' => 1, 'column_2' => 2]
);
```

Read:

```
$select = $write->select()
    ->from(['tbl' => $table], ['entity_id', 'company'])
    ->join(['tbl2' => $table2], 'tbl.entity_id = tbl2.product_id', ['stuff'])
    ->where('name LIKE ?', "%{$name}%")
    ->group('company');
$results = $write->fetchAll($select);
```

Update:

```
$write->update(
    $table,
    ['column_1' => 3, 'column_2' => 4],
    ['entity_id = ?' => 123]
);
```

Delete:

```
$write->delete(
    $table,
    ['entity_id IN (?)' => [123, 456]]
);
```

Insert Multiple:

```
$rows = [
    ['col_1'=>'value1', 'col_2'=>'value2', 'col_3'=>'value3'],
    ['col_1'=>'value3', 'col_2'=>'value4', 'col_3'=>'value5'],
];
$write->insertMultiple($table, $rows);
```

Insert Update On Duplicate:

```
$data = [];
$data[] = [
    'sku' => $sku,
    'name' => $name
];
$write->insertOnDuplicate(
    $table,
    $data, // Could also be an array of rows like insertMultiple
    ['name'] // this is the fields that will be updated in case of duplication
);
```

Comment: Nice. Taught me database query logic in Magento.

Comment: Wow, I wish I knew this was possible when I started working on Magento years back. Great explanation!