# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract::_canUpdateAttribute()

Tags: magento-1.9, save

I am getting an error while trying to pragmatically remove products from some categories.

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract::_canUpdateAttribute() must be of
>   the type array, null given, called in
>   /xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on
>   line 1225 and defined in
>   /xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php:540
>
> Stack trace: 
>   #0 /xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1225):
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->_canUpdateAttribute(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute), '2019-01-14 00:0...', NULL)
>
> #1 /xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1123):
>   Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_collectSaveData(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
>
> #2 /xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
>
> #3 /home/admin/domains/gr in /xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php
>   on line 540

And my code:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($specialCategoryId)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('special_to_date', 'category_ids'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('lteq' => date("Y-m-d")));

foreach ($products as $product) {

    $oldCategories = $product->getCategoryIds();
    $newCategories = array_diff($oldCategories, $specialCategoryIds);

    if($oldCategories != $newCategories){
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getEntityId());

        $_product->setCategoryIds($newCategories);

        Mage::log('Product ID: ' .$product->getEntityId(), null, 'RemoveFromCategoryLog.log', true);
        try {
            $_product->save();
        } catch(Exception  $e){
            Mage::log($e->getMessage(), null, 'RemoveFromCategoryLog.log', true);
        }
    }
}
```

Loading the product did not solve it. And as there are lots of products i am reluctant to use category_api.

Comment: you can get a category id  have u check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using SQL is an option for you, you can delete and add entries in the table `catalog_category_product`

For example, if you want to delete product with product_id = 1 from category with category_id = 99 use this statement:

```
delete from catalog_category_product where product_id = 1 and category_id = 99;
```

To assign the product with product_id = 1 to category with category_id = 77 (on first position) use this statement:

```
insert into catalog_category_product (category_id,product_id,position) values (77,1,1);
```

After doing this you need to rebuild the category index and everything is done.

Otherwise consider to use `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api` and the methods `assignProduct` and `updateProduct`.
The product model doesn't save the categoryIds you set with `setCategoryIds()` - since you need a position for the product in a category.

Answer (score 1):

Try by writing this below line of code at the beginning of your custom script

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

My final solution using sql.

```
resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$write = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$table = 'catalog_category_product';

$write->delete(
    $table,
    array(
      'category_id = ?' => $catId,
      'product_id = ?' => $product->getEntityId()
    )
);
```

Based on answers from @HelgeB and @Shadowbob in answer
[Magento 1 SQL Queries](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61796/magento-1-sql-queries)